# How does the browser know what to read when opening a file on the page

Tags: html, dom, browser

Websites will call style, js, and other pages (e.g. `https://example.com/style/main.css`).

However, when I go to these pages, and inspect them, I get an html page that looks like this:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
.foo{
     color: blue;
}
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

It appears to be an HTML file. How does the browser know what to read, and also, why is it in this format, and not just css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When linking to an external file such as CSS or JS, the browser loads and interprets the files in the order that they are listed in the HTML page.

With regard to the why a CSS file appears as HTML when loaded by the browser, this is because of how web browsers are programmed to work. A browser isn't meant to display a raw CSS or JS file (*browsers are meant to load the files into memory and execute actions baed on the code*), so as a work around most browsers will load the contents of the CSS or JS file as the body of an HTML page using the `<pre>` to format the content.